# Return invalid submission if no Checkbox is checked on initial load of the page

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, jquery-plugins, onload

I need my error handlers to fire if the form is submitted without any selection on initial load. If I add .prop('required', true) on each checkbox on document ready function, it would include other checkboxes that has values loaded from our db. Which means my error handler would fire although there are already fields selected.

So I tried this code outside my 'onsubmit' function:

```
$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').filter(':checked').length;
$('.cboxgrp').each(function(){
if(cboxgrp===0){
$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('require',true);}
```

It works as expected on initial submission attempt, it fires my error handlers if the form doesn't have any checkboxes selected, however, if I tested my other forms that has checkboxes already selected, my error handlers would also be triggered.

This is my current code below:

```
$(#form).on('submit', function(){
$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').filter(':checked').length;
$('.cboxgrp').each(function(){
if(cboxgrp===0){
$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('require',true);}});
```

The result on the above code is 1 mouseclick(literally) more than what I expected to happen. This would set the checkboxes to required on the first click of the submit button, then on the second try is shows my error handlers.

Is there a way for my error handlers to fire on initial load without setting the checkboxes to 'required' on document ready?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form :checkbox', this).each(function(){
     var checkbox = $(this);
     if( ! checkbox.is(':checked')){
       checkbox.prop('required', true);
     }
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried you suggestion, it includes all the checkboxes still.

Answer (score -2):

try `$(this).find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('required',true);`

Comment: I tried this as well. Forms that already has some selection in it on initial load would also fire my errorHandler.